# Replacing an owned Vector by a reference or const pointer causes a 20% drop in performance

Tags: rust

I have a Rust application that stores a huge vector called 'Heap' in a struct:

```rust
pub struct Heap {
  pub data: Vec<(AtomicU32, AtomicU32)>,
}

pub struct Net {
  heap: Heap,
  ...
}
```

The application performs quite well. I now am preparing it for a parallel version. To do it:

1. Multiple threads must access the same shared Heap;
2. Multiple threads must have its own Net instance;

Sadly, the borrow checker will NOT allow me to have multiple `Net` objects "owning" the same `Heap` object. The solution should be straightforward, though: turn `Heap` into a reference, like this:

```rust
pub struct Net<'a> {
  heap: &'a Heap,
  ...
}
```

Easy, right? Except by just changing this, **and nothing else**, the performance of my application drops by 20%, which isn't acceptable. Because of that, I tried another approach, and changed to:

```rust
pub struct Net<'a> {
  heap: *const Heap,
  ...
}
```

But it also caused a 20% drop in performance. I then tried:

```rust
pub struct Net<'a> {
  heap: Arc<Heap>
  ...
}
```

Which caused a 20% drop in performance. Finally, I also tried replacing Vec by a boxed slide, but it also caused a 20% drop in performance.

Long story short, anything I do to satisfy the borrow checker causes my program's performance to drop 20%, even though these programs should be identical. Sadly, the program is too big and contrived to isolate this effect, but [here](https://github.com/HigherOrderCO/hvm-core/blob/959f888948235913e9b3ac24e8cc7d4c16885979/src/run.rs#L68) is the relevant code. To benchmark, do `cargo install --path .`, then `cd examples; hvmc run burn.hvmc`.

What can be done in this situation?

Comment: The only thing I can imagine that can cause a loss in performance is the extra indirection (although I didn't think it can cause that big loss). Try using a slice: `&[(AtomicU32, AtomicU32)]`.

Comment: I hope you benchmarked a release build.

Comment: Yep, release with all the optimizations on. I've tried a boxed slice. What do you mean by just a slice? It needs to be boxed, no? The array size is known (always 2GB exactly), what is the least indirection way to do it?

Comment: I think Chayim means a slice reference `&[(AtomicU32, AtomicU32)]` not a boxed slice, a reference to a slice. The boxed slice still will result in a double indirection. You can get a slice reference from a `Vec` or a boxed slice.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman looking at the code, the heap seems to be touched *a lot*, so I would not be surprised if an additional dereference was a significant hit. On the other hand it looks like the heap might have a fixed size (set at initialisation and never updated), so an arc-boxed slice (`Arc<[(AtomicU32, AtomicU32)]>`) might be an option.

Comment: @Masklinn True, but if they can use a reference, why use an `Arc`?

Comment: I think I see what you mean, there were 2 indirections due to Heap storing a Box. I've updated it to (I believe) 1 indirection, and it indeed recovered part of the lost performance. It is still slightly slower than a Vec, but not much.

Here are the updated types: https://github.com/HigherOrderCO/hvm-core/blob/485343a5e51646a4705cf30ffec78d9f09192668/src/run.rs#L68

Thanks for the hint. Should we turn this into an answer?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I assumed things could be moved around is all. You're right that if that's unnecessary then a slice should be even better. Anyway there seems to be other effects at play, swapping the vec for an arc (which is easy and requires no restructuring) still slowed the benchmark from 11.864 s ±  0.896 s to 12.597 s ±  0.916 s on my machine, the high bound is the same but the low bound is a touch higher, and the average is obviously significantly higher. Interestingly I see a significant increase in system time (from ~1s to 1.5).

Comment: Printing the sizes there seem to be a lot of heaps being initialised, it might be worth preallocating the vec or boxed slice to avoid reallocations.

Comment: How did you "print the sizes"? @Masklinn

Comment: @MaiaVictor just added an `eprintln!("{size}")` in the heap constructor, on burn it shows 25 heaps of 256K and one heap of 256M being constructed, however preallocating the vector (using `Vec::with_capacity(size)` does not seem to have a positive effect, on my machine the variance gets a touch lower but the average gets worse (12.716 s ±  0.714 s). At that point I can only recommend looking at the codegen and / or profiling, I've no clue what could be happening.

Comment: I see, we create a bunch of small heaps to set up the program and build a separate lookup object, but they're thrown away before the real computation begins, so all that is left is the 2 GB buffer.

Comment: @MaiaVictor yeah but without knowing the exact behaviour of the program I figured maybe the initialisation was a significant part of the runtime (turns out that hypothesis is wrong, or at least wrong for the allocating-and-initialising-the-heaps bit)

Comment: Note that if you will use range as iterators and `collect()`, both `Vec` and `Arc` will do exactly one allocation.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed in the comments, the issue was that, on the code below:

```rust
pub struct Heap {
  pub data: Vec<(AtomicU32, AtomicU32)>,
}

pub struct Net<'a> {
  heap: &'a Heap,
  ...
}
```

There are two indirections: `net.heap` is a pointer to a struct, and then `Heap.data` is a pointer to a buffer. By changing it to:

```
pub type Data = [(AtomicU32, AtomicU32)];

pub struct Heap<'a> {
  pub data: &'a Data,
}

// A interaction combinator net.
pub struct Net<'a> {
  pub heap: Heap<'a>, // nodes
```

We now only have one pointer (`heap.data`, to the buffer), reverting the performance drop.

Comment: Still feel confused about why the indirection matters in the top code, i.e. won't the compiler make a zero-cost abstraction for you as if there was no indirection? I also wonder if there is any possibility that, in the bottom code, the better performance is gained due to *slice indexing* (compared to *vector indexing*) and you've paid for the cost of indirection from vec to slice aforehand (during the initialization of `net`).